# Image from container is going down on action

Tags: android, html, css, android-webview, mobile-browser

I made a webapp with mobile-first design in mind. This is used in a Android WebView but it's not working properly. There is side nav positioned fixed with a background image set to cover that is going to change position in the default Browser and WebView [see screenshots]

The problem occur when you scroll down a little bit and click one icon from the left side nav. The page is going to reload and when is done, the background image from side nav is scrolled down approximately with the same distance you scrolled.

**Desktop browser(firefox/chrome/safari)**: I can use the nav menu or the pagination and everything works as I expect. The problem with scroll doesn't occur

**Mobile browser(firefox/chrome/safari)**: Everything seems to work. The problem with scroll doesn't occur.

**Mobile browser(default: Browser [the one with blue logo])**: Not working properly

[image: Browser1]
[image: Browser2]

**And WebView:**

[image: WebView1]
[image: WebView2]

The code for side nav:

```
#side_nav
  width: 70px
  position: fixed
  background: url(image_path('webapp/menubar.png')) no-repeat scroll 0 -90px
  background-size: cover
  height: 100%

  .active
    color: white

  @each $image in $images
    ##{$image}
      background: url(image_path('webapp/index_#{$image}.png')) no-repeat
      background-size: cover
      height: 40px
      width: 40px
      margin: 0 auto

  @each $image in $images
    ##{$image}.active
      background: url(image_path('webapp/index_#{$image}_active.png')) no-repeat
      background-size: cover
      height: 40px
      width: 40px
      margin: 0 auto

  p
    margin: 0
    font-size: 12px
    color: $color-text-inactive

  a
    text-decoration: none
```

Live website: http://salonapp.ro/saloane

I'm pretty sure there is some kind of problem related how the default Browser from Android is loading CSS or something broken with my CSS. The last problem I observed on the mobile was the `background-size` property which has to be declared in separate line.

If you put `url("...") no-repeat scroll 0 -90px / cover  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` doesn't seem to recognize the cover.

If you guys need other code please ask for it. I won't provide a jsfiddle because I posted the production website.

Thank you

EDIT: It's fixed. Seems like mobile browser and Android WebView handle different the distance between elements that are positioned absolute/fixed and relative elements. In the #side_nav I specify top: 40px and for the destkop site is top: 80px [But I find this quite strange since all modern browsers handle this kind of situation by themselves]

Comment: This happens to my site on my Android all the time. My solution is to define a background color that matches the image closely so that when the glitch happens, the text is still readable well. I suspect it's an optimization gone wrong.